# Reverse Seague IOS

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

Could you explain me please, how could I do this.
First table view has a static cell with Auto-lock text, you choose it and it reveals new table view with options, when you choose 5 minutes for example, it returns the selected info to previous cell. Thanks a lot

[image: ios1]
[image: ios2]

Comment: You can use push segue with navigation controller.

Comment: @user2894531 you shouldn't use a push segue to go back to a previous controller -- that just creates a new instance of that controller, it doesn't actually "go back".

Comment: @rdelmar: If he has used a push segue with navigation controller pressing back button automatically will take him to the previous controller

Comment: @user2894531, yes, I'm aware of that, but you said in your comment to use a push segue -- he's already using a push to go forward, I assumed you were saying to use a push going back.

Comment: No I dint mean like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to reverse segue instead you can use **popViewControllerAnimated**

At the time of cell selection(**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**), you can put the below code

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

For data passing, you can use **delegate** methods

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm